# Node HTTP Delete request no longer works after upgrading from 0.10.40

Tags: node.js, http, elasticsearch

I've been trying to upgrade most of my node stuff to 4.x but am running into some problems with executing delete queries to Elasticsearch. The following worked on 0.10.40 and prior, but does not work on 4.x.x or 5.7.0. I'm out of ideas, it appears that node doesn't send the body of my request as the error I get back from Elasticsearch is `{"error":"ActionRequestValidationException[Validation Failed: 1: source is missing;]","status":400}`.

```
var http = require('http');
var request = http.request({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 9200,
    path: 'test/col/_query',
    method: 'DELETE'
});

request.on('response', function(res) {
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', function(response) {
        if(response.indexOf('"failed":0') === -1) {
            console.log('Failed. Response: ', response);
            process.exit(1);
        }
    });
    res.on('end',  function() {
        console.log('completed successfully');
        process.exit(0);
    });
});
request.on('error', function(err) { cb(err); });

var q = {
    query: {
        "bool": {
            "must_not": [
                {"ids": {"values": ['1','2','3'] } }
            ]
        }
    }
};

request.write(JSON.stringify(q));
request.end();
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

HTTP DELETE requests are not supposed to contain a payload. However, in 0.10 it was supported due to the fact that the `Transfer-Encoding: Chunked` HTTP header was being sent along the request even if no payload was sent to the server. This was fixed in [0.11.14](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#20140924-version-01114-unstable) by [issue 6164](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/6164).

From now on, if you really need to send a body with a DELETE request, you also need to add a `Content-Length` header specifying the length of what you're sending, otherwise the server will disregard any payload.

So if you construct your request like this, it will work:

```
var q = {
    query: {
        "bool": {
            "must_not": [
                {"ids": {"values": ['1','2','3'] } }
            ]
        }
    }
};
var payload = JSON.stringify(q);

var request = http.request({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 9200,
    path: 'test/col/_query',
    method: 'DELETE',
    headers: {                                    <--- add this
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(payload)
    }
});

...

request.write(payload);
request.end();
```

Comment: Thanks, i was banging my head from yesterday wondering why DELETE is not working but other methods are. Saved the day!!